# Pygame: Reset the Angle after Rotation

Tags: python, pygame

The helicopter flies from right to left. When a key is pressed it crashes. In the code excerpt, it flies to the bottom right corner.
Then another helicopter should come from the left and fly straight ahead to the right. That doesn't happen. He comes from the left and immediately falls again, although the angle has been reset.

---

```
breite,hoehe = 1200,800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((breite,hoehe))

class Helikopter(pygame.sprite.Sprite):       
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)   
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Bilder/heli1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.img = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(160,60))
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()        
        self.rect.x = - 20
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(100,300)
        self.speed = 10
        self.absturz = False
        self.angle = 0  

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 2    
        self.rect.y += 0       
        if self.rect.x > breite or self.rect.y > hoehe:
            self.rect.x = - 20
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(100,300)
            self.absturz == False            
        if self.absturz == True:
            x = breite - self.rect.x 
            y = hoehe - self.rect.y                
            self.dist = math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
            self.rect.x += self.speed *x / self.dist       
            self.rect.y += self.speed *y / self.dist        
            self.angle = math.degrees(-math.atan2(y, x))          
        else:
            self.absturz = False
            self.angle = 0            
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.img, self.angle,1)  

heli_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
heli = Helikopter()
heli_sprites.add(heli)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            heli.absturz = True

    screen.fill((250,0,0))    
    heli_sprites.draw(screen) 
    heli_sprites.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems:

1. `self.absturz == False` is a comparison, but not an assignement
2. `self.absturz` needs to be set `True` when `self.rect` hits the ground (`self.absturz == True`)

```py
class Helikopter(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 2    
        self.rect.y += 0       
        if self.rect.x > breite or self.rect.y > hoehe:
            self.rect.x = - 20
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(100,300)
            
            self.absturz = True           # <---

        # [...]
```